# Python if statement not computing value

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

First baby steps into Python and I'm stuck. I want to print the absolute value of an integer that is input by the user. If the integer that is input is a negative value, I want it to return a positive value. I'm converting the string to an integer fine, I'm storing the input 'number' fine, but if I input a negative number it's not doing the eval of the if statement and converting to a positive number by `* -1` as you see below. I'm at a loss, should I be defining another variable somewhere here?

```
number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))

if number <= 0:
    number = number * -1
```

Comment: What's happening instead? You don't seem to be doing anything with the `number` afterwards, at least, not in this code.

Comment: The code you present works (apart from the indentation error at `if`). But a simpler way to do it is `number = abs(int(input('Please enter a number: ')))`.

Comment: Wow, `number = abs(int(input('Please enter a number: ')))` actually works. Objective met, but I still want to know why the if statement isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number:"))

if num <= 0:
    num = abs(num)
```

Python has a lot of built-in functions that help do simple tasks like this.
The abs() function returns the absolute value of any float/int/etc. you put into it.

You can also do this all in one line if you wish, you would use the same abs() function. This time around it can be in a try-except block which will handle any bad input like "18asdfnsjkdf" for example.

```
try:
    num = abs(int(input("Enter a number:")))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: I don't think it answer the question about the OP's code (also the `if`-clause is redundant if you use `abs`).

Comment: If you are calling `abs()` then there is no need to test `if num <= 0:`

Answer (score 0):

I performed the tests on my machine and the operation went correctly. Is it returning an error for you?

[image]

As a suggestion, you can also use the `abs()` function instead of multiplying by -1 to return the absolute value of a number.

Example :

```
abs(-5) ---> 5
abs(5) ---> 5
```

Comment: Note I'm using IDLE, and when I evaluate 'number' after it still returns any negative number I've input as still being that negative number.

Also tried 

`number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))  
 if number <= 0:  
   abs(number)
 
print(number)`

Still same thing

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, add a print statement and be careful of indentation issues:

```
number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))  
if number <= 0:  
  number = number * -1 
print(number)
```

Output is:

```
Please enter a number: -5
5
```